# Adding property to object from async operation in Rx.js

Tags: javascript, promise, reactive-programming, rxjs

Let's say I have a observable coming in, something like this below. Here, `company` has a method `website`. I'd like to add a new property to this object called `websiteStatusCode` that is a number. The value of `websiteStatusCode` the status code for the website. I have to make an HTTP request to the server and I want to store the status code. We have a `request` promise that returns `response.statusCode`.

```
companyStream.map(company => {
  // company.website
})
```

Do I simply open the promise within the map? Do I have to wrap the promise within a `Rx.Observable.fromPromise` and return that?

```
companyStream.map(company => {
  if (!company.website) {
    company.websiteStatusCode = false
    return company
  }
  return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(request(company.website).then(request => {
    company.websiteStatusCode = request.statusCode
    return company
  }))
})
```

Is this valid code above? Is there a better way to tap into object properties with Rx that's not so verbose?